# Jquery Toggle not toggling class on mobile

Tags: jquery, css

I have this website here: http://annapiotrowski.com/ and I have a menu option labeled Services and that is dropdown menu and the code for that looks like this:

```
<li class="dropdown menu-services"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="menu-online"><a href="http://annapiotrowski.com/online-health-coaching/">Online</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown menu-in-person"><a href="#">In Person</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="menu-classes"><a href="http://annapiotrowski.com/classes/">Classes</a></li>
        <li class="menu-corporate-wellness"><a href="http://annapiotrowski.com/corporate-wellness/">Corporate Wellness</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

On mobile you should be able to click on Services and it will expand the menu and show the items inside the dropdown menu, I am using this jquery to toggle it:

```
<script>

(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
        if (newWindowWidth < 768) {

        $(".dropdown").on("click", function() {

        $(".dropdown").toggleClass("open");


        });

        }

    });

})( jQuery );

</script>
```

When the site is at the top of the page I am able to click on the Services menu item and see the items inside the dropdown menu.

However if I scroll down a bit and try to do it mid-page it does not working at all :( when I click on Services, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried this:

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
        if (newWindowWidth < 768) {

        $(".dropdown").on("click", function() {

        $(".dropdown").toggleClass("open");


        });

        $(".dropdown").off("click").on("click", function() { $(".dropdown").toggleClass("open"); });

        }

    });

})( jQuery );
```

Still did not work.

Comment: I took a look at your website from chrome developer tools in mobile view. I can see the problem after scrolling. when I ran the below code from console, it worked fine. jQuery(".dropdown").off("click").on("click", function() {
     jQuery(".dropdown").toggleClass("open");
 });

Comment: I tried your solution, did not work, I updated my question.

Comment: I made some changes. Try this,                                     $(".dropdown").off("click").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("open"); 
    $(this).find(".dropdown").toggleClass("open");
 });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "context" (this) in the click handler to identify the target of click event. Please replace your click handler with the following code, it should work. I verified it on your website.

```
 $(".dropdown").off("click").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("open"); 
    $(this).find(".dropdown").toggleClass("open");
 });
```

Comment: That's interesting. could you run the above code on chrome dev tools console and see if that works for you too?

Comment: Got it. I debugged your website in console. when your document.ready script runs, $(".dropdown") returns only two "dropdown" html elments which belong to your first menu when user has not scrolled. your scroll menu "dropdown" is not even available hence jquery has not attached any click event handler to it.  This is the reason it works when you add the handlers from console.

Comment: Okay....I have tried bind events and that did not work :( It actually broke my other dropdown.

Comment: In your main.js, in ready() method,  just before you the line  "jQuery(window).trigger('hashchange');"   add the above event handlers $(".dropdown").off("click").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("open"); 
    $(this).find(".dropdown").toggleClass("open");
 });            By this time your both drop downs would be available, then you can add the event handlers on both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191003/discussion-between-murali-nepalli-and-user979331).

Comment: I added your code to main.js, still does not work :(

Comment: In your main.js , It throws the error "$ is not a function" so replace the symbol '$' with "jQuery".   so remove replace the line you added with 
 jQuery(".dropdown").off("click").on("click", function() { jQuery(this).toggleClass("open"); jQuery(this).find(".dropdown").toggleClass("open"); });

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a case when you're on mobile devices, the issue is because you have 2 menu elements on the DOM.

If you are on the top of the page, click the Services menu item ( it should work ) and leave it open, and THEN scroll down, you should be able to see the 2nd menu element now in view.

You'll just have to adjust your js to deal with the 2nd menu.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, what should I adjust my js code to what?